# What percent of first post-IPO earnings reports are disappointing?

Tags: stock-analysis, ipo, online-data-source, market-data, statistics

It seems like every time a company has its IPO, the next earnings report fails to meet expectations and the stock price plummets. Shouldn't expectations be lower considering the frequency at which this happens? Is there a way to find exact statistics on stock price changes following first post-IPO earnings reports?